# Are there valid use cases for extending from a normal selector after Sass 3.2?

Tags: css, sass

Placeholders were introduced in Sass 3.2. This [blog post](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2013/07/11/sass-placeholders-versus-mixins-and-extends/) advises us not to extend normal selectors, and almost always extend from a placeholder, because [`@extend` will add onto all the selectors it is extending from](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend), but this does not apply to placeholders.

**The follow Sass file...**

```
.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
.sidebar .signup .button {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
.article a {
  @extend .button;
}
```

**...will generate...**

```
.button, .article a { /* This is probably what you intended to do */
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

/* But it also generates this combinational mess */
.sidebar .signup .button, .sidebar .signup .article a, .article .sidebar .signup a {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```

And using placeholders will prevent this.

So are there valid use cases for extending from a normal selector after Sass 3.2?

Comment: Most of the time the _"combinational mess"_ is exactly what you want to generate as far as I see.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem here is.  If the generated result isn't what you want, then don't do it.  Seems pretty simple to me.

Comment: @cimmanon "If the generated result isn't what you want, then don't do it." - What about trying to understand the concepts? ...and also, if it is so simple to you, do you care to try provide an answer?

Comment: @dayuloli Because I don't answer questions that are too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, there are cases when you can use it but always you have not a very good reason to do it, it is better avoid it and use the placeholders to extend.

You only should extend one class in the case you are sure that they are very close related and the amount of code to extend is relevant.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all.